# Explanation of $ \mathcal{L}^{p} $ spaces for each of it's possible abstract venues.

Tags: analysis, vector-spaces, lebesgue-integral, lebesgue-measure

I am aware of the meaning of the subspace of Lp:

$$ l^{p} = \sum_{i}^{\infty}|x_{i}|^{p} < \infty $$

in terms of an infinite dimensional vector/tensor space;

$$ \bar{V} =  \sum_{p=1}^{\infty} \sum_{i=1}^{\infty}\hat{e}^{p}_{i}x^{p}_{i} $$

I am asking for a clarification of p-integral functions in abstract measure spaces and what the p index denotes in:

$$ \mathcal{L}^{p} (M, \sum, \mu) = \int_{M} |f|^{p} .d \mu < \infty $$

Also how normalization of a vector:

$$ ||V|| = \frac{V}{|V|} $$

is related to the definition in Banach spaces (normed) with the pth root:

for

$$ ||f||_{p} :=  (\int_{M}|f|^{p} . d \mu )^{\frac{1}{p}} $$

I am having trouble visualizing p-integrals and p-normalisation because the notation in my book is so compact.

Comment: I don't think you will get much here except when $p=1,2$ or $\infty $. The other spaces do not have much of a particular importance.

Comment: Very roughly speaking, as $p$ increases, $L^p$ cares more about big values even though they are confined to small sets. For example, you might compute the $L^p$ norm of the function $x^{-1/2}$ on $(0,1]$ with the Lebesgue measure.

Comment: Such that p denotes a dimensional function in the measure space where $$ f^{p} \in \sum_{\lambda} \times \Gamma_{\mu} $$ since a sigma product algebra in this is $$ \int_{M} ( \int_{M} |f|^{p} d \mu) d \lambda $$ then when p = 2, we have the functions of the variables in the set M: $$ ( x \in X \subseteq \sum , y \in Y \subseteq \Gamma )\subseteq M $$ such that $$ f^{x} $$ and $$ f^{y} $$ are now evaluated:
$$ \int_{X} f^{y} d \lambda + \int_{Y} f^{x} d \mu $$